# Laravel: returning results from multiple related tables using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 and in particular I'm looking for an answer that uses eloquent ORM.

I have a table "**tasks**" which containers a **client_id** and a **user_id** assigned to each row.

**client_id** refers to a client on a "**clients**" table and **user_id** refers to a user on a "**users**" table.

**What I want to do**: show all tasks and display the "**clients**" **name** and "**users**" **first_name**

So the result would look like this in my (blade) view:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $task->user->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $task->client->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $task->description }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The above view spits out the $task->client->name perfectly fine but unfortunately shows a "Trying to get property of non-object" when I add the line $task->user->first_name

My controller looks like this:

```
$tasks = Task::with(array('user', 'client'))->get();
return View::make('index', compact('tasks'));
```

As I understand it my models make a difference too, so my models look like this:

```
class Task extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array();

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Client');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany('Project', 'client_id');
    }
}
```

**Any ideas on how to make this work?** I've been scratching my head for a while - also note I'm not a database relationship pro so the simpler the explanation the better :)

Comment: It would seem to me that your Tasks table is a pivot table in a many-to-many relation. You should probably use Eloquent's belongsToMany() method to link Client and User directly. See [this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) for info on how to add additional fields to your pivot table.

Comment: Hi @cuewizchris I took a look at the documentation and I can't work out how to translate their example of User/Role/Pivot to my needs. Are you saying I should change my hasMany() to toMany()? I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just worked through this and learned quite a few things myself.  What I did was setup a many to many relationship between `users` and `clients` and created a pivot table for handling the relationship called `tasks` which also stores the description for each task.

It was too much to type here, but you can check out my code at http://paste.laravel.com/Fpv

Comment: Absolutely genius. Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. However (and I admit this is beyond the scope of my question) - it gets really complicated / breaks when you try add pagination and/or orderBy (e.g. order by created_at DESC) statements to your eloquent query in your controller :) obviously with the orderBy created_at it's trying to get the user's created_at date not the task's created_at date.

Comment: I've tried a few things, but it always seems to fail when I try to paginate or orderBy when eager loading.  I am assuming the best way to do this would be to use array_slice for paginate and whatever sorting function would be appropriate to you.

Comment: It is never "too much to type here". I can't resolve your link.

Comment: downvote because an answer should include a complete answer - not just a  suggestion and a link (especially when the link is a broken one)

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relationships can be done like this with Eloquent:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'tasks', 'client_id')->withPivot('description');
    }
}
```

and the inverse relationship...

```
class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'tasks', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Haven't tested this, but it should be correct.

Comment: I apologise for my lack of knowledge and the number of questions, but what would my eloquent query look like in my controller?